# Flask api calls work locally but sometimes recieve outdated data when deployed on heroku (react frontend)

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, heroku, caching

I have a website that when tested locally work perfectly; however, when I deploy it it seems to seemingly randomly get incorrect/outdated JSON data. It is a voting app so if the ballot is c1,c2,c3 and I remove c3 then c3 will sometimes appear and sometimes it wont. Disabling cache in firefox web dev tools does not seem to fix it and neither does ctrl f5.

I have tried adding cachebusting with timestamps and no cache headers on both the frontend and backend.
Frontend example

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchVotingStatus = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(`/get_voting_status?_t=${timestamp}`, {
          method: 'GET',
          headers: {
            'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, no-store',
            'Pragma': 'no-cache',
            'Expires': '0',
          },
        })
        const data = await response.json();
        if (!data.voting_status.President) {
          // Voting for President is closed, redirect to the home page
          navigate('/');
        } else {
          // Voting is open, fetch candidates
            fetchCandidates();
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching voting status:', error);
      }
    };def add_no_cache_headers(response):
    response.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0'
    response.headers['Pragma'] = 'no-cache'
    response.headers['Expires'] = '0'
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    return response

@app.after_request
def apply_no_cache(response):
    no_cache_routes = [
        'no_cache', 'get_voter',
        'getJsonVoteStatus', 'handle_submit_vote', 'open_vote', 'close_vote',
        'pres_candidates', 'memb_candidates', 'AO_candidates', 'SE_candidates',
        'MC_candidates', 'finance_candidates', 'IandB_candidates', 'othervote_prompt',
        'othervote_options', 'open_vote', 'close_vote'
    ]

    if request.endpoint in no_cache_routes:
        return add_no_cache_headers(response)
    return response
```

Backend example

```
def add_no_cache_headers(response):
    response.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0'
    response.headers['Pragma'] = 'no-cache'
    response.headers['Expires'] = '0'
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    return response

@app.after_request
def apply_no_cache(response):
    no_cache_routes = [
        'no_cache', 'get_voter',
        'getJsonVoteStatus', 'handle_submit_vote', 'open_vote', 'close_vote',
        'pres_candidates', 'memb_candidates', 'AO_candidates', 'SE_candidates',
        'MC_candidates', 'finance_candidates', 'IandB_candidates', 'othervote_prompt',
        'othervote_options', 'open_vote', 'close_vote'
    ]

    if request.endpoint in no_cache_routes:
        return add_no_cache_headers(response)
    return response
```

I am using some global variables on the backend so maybe data is persisting somehow? I am starting to wonder if the issue lies in heroku since the app works locally and pulls all teh correct data

Answer (score 0):

To persist data and keep them consistent for a Heroku app, the app must have a [data store](https://elements.heroku.com/addons#data-stores) like [Heroku Data for Redis](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/heroku-redis). Global variables in an app process as well as data stored on files are discarded when the [web dyno restarts](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#restarting). If the app is running more than one web dyno, there is no mechanism that synchronizes global variables or temporally files between the running web dynos.

Comment: Just to clarify I am using a google sheet as a "database" (for non tech people to avoid needing a separate interface) all the data is hosted there and its just adding and removing names from cells. Would I still need a data store for that purpose? sorry if the question is trivial I am a student and trying to learn.

Comment: I'm sorry that I'm not familiar with Google sheets being used as a database so please ignore this if it doesn't fit your use: Might your "global variables" hold reference to the Google sheets? In that case, I'd suspect inconsistencies might be observed when the app has more than one processes running where each of the process has its own global variables referring to the Google sheets in a different state.